# WebSocketClient from android does not connect to the server

Tags: java, android, websocket

I am new to websockets. I have created the application on android on WebSocketClient and i try to connect to my WebSocket server on computer, but i get errors.

Here what i understood:

1. The computer is not received requests from android client (using Wireshark).
2. The server actually works (i tryed to use the same websocket client, but on my computer)

Stack trace:

```
javax.websocket.DeploymentException: Connection failed.
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket._connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:413)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.access$000(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:103)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:228)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket$1.call(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:224)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientSocket.connect(GrizzlyClientSocket.java:242)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.container.grizzly.client.GrizzlyClientContainer.openClientSocket(GrizzlyClientContainer.java:95)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3$1.run(ClientManager.java:626)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$3.run(ClientManager.java:673)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:487)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager$SameThreadExecutorService.execute(ClientManager.java:826)
at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:123)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:496)
at org.glassfish.tyrus.client.ClientManager.connectToServer(ClientManager.java:312)
at com.example.deem.ExampleClient.start(AuthActivity.java:163)
at com.example.deem.AuthActivity$1.onClick(AuthActivity.java:59)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7570)
at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7540)
at android.view.View.-$$Nest$mperformClickInternal(Unknown Source:0)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:29710)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:942)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:240)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:351)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8422)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:584)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1013)
```

Client:

```
@ClientEndpoint
public class ExampleClient {
    private static Session session;

    @OnOpen
    public void onOpen(Session session) {
        this.session = session;
        System.out.println(format("Connection established. session id: %s", session.getId()));
    }

    @OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message) {
        System.out.println(message);
    }

    public static void sendMessage(String message) {
        if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
            session.getAsyncRemote().sendText(message);
        }
    }

    public void start() {
        WebSocketContainer container = ContainerProvider.getWebSocketContainer();
        try {
            URI uri = new URI("ws://192.168.1.104:8025/ws/chat");
            container.connectToServer(ExampleClient.class, uri);
            ExampleClient.sendMessage("str");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Сервер:

```
@javax.websocket.server.ServerEndpoint(value = "/chat")
public class MessengerEndPoint {


    @javax.websocket.OnOpen
    public void onOpen(javax.websocket.Session session) {
        System.out.println("Connect session");
    }

    @javax.websocket.OnMessage
    public void onMessage(String message, javax.websocket.Session session) throws IOException, javax.websocket.EncodeException {
        System.out.println("Message " + message);
    }

    @javax.websocket.OnClose
    public void onClose(javax.websocket.Session session) throws IOException, EncodeException {
    }

public static void main(String[] args) {
        org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server server = new org.glassfish.tyrus.server.Server
                ("localhost", 8025, "/ws", MessengerEndPoint.class);

        try {
            server.start();
            System.out.println("Press any key to stop the server..");
            new Scanner(System.in).nextLine();
        } catch (javax.websocket.DeploymentException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        } finally {
            server.stop();
        }

        
    }

}
```

Comment: `"localhost"` Why that value for that parameter? What is it for? To bind to localhost? Dont bind at all or bind to 0.0.0.0 if you want to enable acces from net.

Comment: I tried to change this parameter but didn't know to use "0.0.0.0". But it still didn't help. Perhaps this was one of the problems.

Comment: Try -for testing- to connect from a different computer in your network. Not from an Android device.